# How to pass std::shared_ptr to callback through unsigned long?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have an old C-style library that uses callback with unsigned long for user  argument and I want to pass my shared_ptr to callback so that reference count is incremented.

```
void callback( unsigned long arg ) {
  std::shared_ptr<my_class> ptr = ??? arg ???
}

void starter_function() {
  std::shared_ptr<my_class> ptr = std::make_shared<my_class>();

  unsigned long arg = ??? ptr ???
  // pass to library so it may be used by callback
}
```

Currently I use get() on shared_ptr and then use C-style cast but this creates a problem when start_function goes out of scope.

Comment: as you see by the answers there are ideas but each has advantages/disadvantages. You need to be aware about what is important for you project here. Hope one of the "nice" solutions helps you here.

Answer (score 9):

Create a static store (which can be based on `std::map<unsigned long, std::shared_ptr<T>>`).  Provide functions to:

- register a shared pointer in the store (which saves it in the map, and returns a unique long).
- retrieve the `shared_ptr` corresponding to a particular unsigned long
- remove a particular unsigned long

(The last two functions can be combined).

This has the attraction of not needing to do any dodgy casts between pointers and unsigned long, and also (if the return value is based on an incrementing counter which you test for uniqueness), makes it much easier to find problems where one object is created, deleted, and then another object created at the same address.

This is a sketch of the idea:  (Note in particular, it is not thread safe!)

```
template typename<T>
class Store
{
    static std::map<unsigned long, std::shared_ptr<T>> store;
    unsigned long h;
    bool contains(unsigned long i)
    {
        return store.find(i) != store.end();
    }
 public:
    unsigned long save(const std::shared_ptr& ptr)
    {
        if (store.size() >= std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max())
        {
            // Handle error.  Only possible if 64 bit program with
            // 32 bit unsigned long.
        }
        // find an unused handle.
        do
        {
            ++h;
        } 
        while(contains(h));  // Not a good approach if there are main long-lived objects, and h might wrap.
        // Store and return handle.
        store[h] = ptr;
        return h;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> retrieve(unsigned long handle)
    {
       if (!contains(handle))
       {
           // handle error
       }
       const auto result = store[handle];
       store.erase(handle);
       return result;
    }
 };
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution. It will have some issues when you rely on RAII during executions, because you either have to manually delete objects or they only get destructed when the binary ends. But if you don't need to rely on releasing the memory when not needed it's nice.

Comment: No, if you can delete the shared_ptrs from the store (as in sample code), then the only live until the callback is finished with them.

Comment: Ah yeah. you run into issued when you use the same "id" twice though. Like register a shared pointer once and give the "id" to 2 callbacks. I mean you can "catch" the error, but it's just something to make users aware of to avoid this. As I said though. Nice solution. :) Gonna keep that in mind when I run across this issue again.

Comment: Right.  Probably the best solution, is to give each callback their own id.  Otherwise, you need to separate the "retrieve" and "remove from store" functions (and call the latter carefully).

Comment: yeah I like retrieve+remove in one better. because you cannot remove if you don't know which callback will be last.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no "goto" solution for this issue. I had this a few times and worked around this differently depending on the situation.

---

An "easy" solution would be (if you have some class there) to store the pointers in a container as class member and so make sure they are being kept alive. Then work with raw-pointer inside the functions. You have to make sure though that your callbacks will not get called when your object is destroyed (so store the callbacks with the objects). This only works smoothly though if you **don't remove** any object from the container. Adding is fine.

---

With threads you pass the shared ptr by reference and then copy it

```
{
    auto sP = make_shared<...>(...);
    thread_start(&sp);
    wait_for_thread_init();
}

void thread_start(std::shared_ptr<...>* ref ) 
    //or unsigned long but you can cast this to a shared_ptr<...>* later.
{
    std::shared_ptr otherPointer = *ref; //here your ref count gets increased
    send_init_complete(); 
    //never use ref from here on. only otherPointer.
}
```

But C++11 has an own thread library which deals with this better, so you should use this when you use threads.

---

Depending on your environment you have to get creative here. And in the end when you have no practical solution you need to work with raw pointers. Just add enough to make commentary that the callbacks should delete those objects etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options. Both options assume that on your platform, an `unsigned long` is big enough to hold a pointer:

1. Convert a pointer to your `std::shared_ptr` to `unsigned long`, and pass it.
2. Use `get()` to retrieve the underlying pointer, and just pass it.

For the second option, it is assumed that your callback does not need to construct another `shared_ptr`; otherwise you'll need to use `enable_shared_from_this`.

Additionally, both options assume that the `shared_ptr`, and the underlying object, will remain in scope when the callback gets invoked. If not:

3. Make a copy of the `shared_ptr` using `new`. You will need to `delete` it after it is no longer needed, and the callback is no longer used.

If, on your platform, an `unsigned long` is not big enough to accomodate a pointer, it gets clumsier. The cleanest solution would be to keep a `std::map<unsigned long, std::shared_ptr<...>>` around, and a counter that assignes a unique `unsigned long` value to each `shared_ptr`, insert the `shared_ptr` into the map, and pass the map's key to the callback.

Comment: copying the object may though be what is not wanted because he he wants to work on the same object. So people have to be aware of this if they rely on wanting to have multiple callbacks on the same instance.